# How does this bitwise hamming(31,26) encoder work in C? (Bitmasking)

Tags: c, encoding, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I understand what the individual operations are (such as the bitwise ANDs an ORs), but I don't understand why they have been used where they have been.

Also, my understanding is that the first set of masks are used to compute parity bits. But I don't understand why the 2nd set of masks have been chosen or what their purpose is. Can anyone help me get my head around this please?

`rawData` is the input word that is to be encoded by the hamming.c function.

Comment: What is `HC_WORD`? `0b...` and `__builtin_popcount` are non-standard.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: `Px_m` constants look amiss.  Please provide usage context or more info about them.

Comment: I'm using GCC. Popcount is a GCC function that counts the number of ones in a binary int.

Comment: Not only is that bad code because it's complex and has zero comments, even ***if*** the `register` keyword does anything, it's applied five out of six times to constants that are each used once.  I hope this code doesn't come from someone trying to teach C...

Comment: @AndrewHenle From a "generic coding" point of view, I agree. However, for people knowing the subject (Hamming codes), the function is quite clear. The application of the function may very well be in a context where performance is critical and performance is clearly prioritized over portability. I agree it seems odd to put `P0_m`, `P1_m`, etc. in `register`s. Even if `__builtin_popcount()` is a macro, it seems unlikely that anything can be gained. I guess it would be better to put `P0`, `P1,`, etc. in registers.

Comment: @nielsen How long did it take you to figure out which bits are the parity bits?  How long would it take you to add comments to the code with that information - probably 30 seconds to maybe a minute, right?  Even you spent more time figuring out exactly what that code does than it would take you to add the comments necessary to explain it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is actually a [standard encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#General_algorithm) for Hamming codes. My main points are that the level of comments needed is very dependent on the context and that this code appears to be made by a skilled person for a specific purpose (not teaching C :-) ). I am not in total disagreement with you, I am just saying that it is not as black and white.

Answer (score 3):

Doing the encoding of a [[31,26] Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code), the function `hammingEncode()` encodes a message `rawData` consisting of 26 message bits by inserting 5 parity bits on positions 0, 1, 3, 7 and 15 (counting bits starting from 0).

The purpose of the part you are asking about:

```
  unsigned int mask1 = 0b11111111111111100000000000;
  unsigned int mask2 = 0b00000000000000011111110000;
  unsigned int mask3 = 0b00000000000000000000001110;
  unsigned int mask4 = 0b00000000000000000000000001;

  encodedData |= (rawData & mask1) << 5;
  encodedData |= (rawData & mask2) << 4;
  encodedData |= (rawData & mask3) << 3;
  encodedData |= (rawData & mask4) << 2;
```

is to move the 26 message bits into the correct positions: 16-30, 8-14, 4-6 and 2 using `mask1`, `mask2`, `mask3` and `mask4` respectively.

After that, the parity bits are calculated and inserted on their correct positions.

Comment: @UpDownStrange Yes, that should be equivalent.